# MS Access VBA check that Word has been closed?

Tags: ms-access, ms-word, vba

I have a project that requires me to open a document in Word and wait while the document is open.  The user then needs to edit the document, print it or save it and then they will close it manually.  When the document (or Word itself) is closed I would like to continue my VBA script in Access.

I have the following code

```
If Len(Dir(sDocName)) > 0 Then
    Dim wordApp As Word.Application
    Dim wordDoc As Word.Document

    ' Launch Word
    Set wordApp = New Word.Application

    ' Open the document
    With wordApp
        Set wordDoc = .Documents.Open(sDocName, , False)

        ' Pass data
        With wordDoc
            .Variables("bmArchitectCompanyName").Value = "Hello"
            .Variables("bmArchitectCompanyAddress").Value = "Hello"
            .Variables("bmArchitectCompanyPostCode").Value = "Hello"
            .Variables("bmArchitectContactFirstName").Value = "Hello"
            .Variables("bmProjectTitle").Value = ProjectTitle
            .Fields.Update
        End With
        .Visible = True
        .Activate

        Do Until wordApp Is Nothing
            ' Wait for Word to be closed
        Loop

        ' Display a success message
        MsgBox "Success!"
    End With
End If
```

However, the do loop never exits.

How do I check if the document I launched through VBA has been closed by the user from my VBA code?

Comment: Where do you close the wordApp? As it is still running the loop will never stop.

Comment: I will close the wordApp object after the if statement (not included above).  I will set the object to Nothing once I know the application has been closed by the user.  I need to know when the application has been closed.

Comment: So the wait loop will have to include a DoEvents loop, then check if the document was closed, otherwise coninue the DoEvents loop.

Answer (score 1):

If your are handling the Word Document in a class module or form module, try declaring a Word.Document object this way:

```
Dim WithEvents w As Word.Document
```

then you can use the Word.Document object event "Close":

```
Private Sub w_Close()

   'Things you want to do when the Word.Document is closed

   'reset object
   set w=nothing

End Sub
```

You must not let then "container" form close or the object terminate unless w is nothing. The form or the object are quiet (or whatever you want them to do) until your Word document is closed.

Comment: Thanks but I don't need to handle the close event, just detect the close event.

Comment: @alcomcomputing I originally wanted to suggest this approach, but couldn't get it to work with a class in Access, which is where your code is executing. But if it really would work, when the event triggers you can call more code - IOW the code that follows sending commands to Word (the MsgBox). You'd need to release the objects at the end of the code where they're declared, however.

Comment: @alcomcomputing There's no diference between handling and detect the close event. To me they are the same since for detecting the closing of a Word Document you must handle the close event first. I don't know other way.

Answer (score 0):

You must yield to the OS using DoEvents, then check if the document was closed, otherwise coninue the DoEvents loop. The following is outline code that I unfortunately could not test.

```
    Do 
        DoEvents
        For i = 1 to wordApp.Documents.Count
            If (wordApp.Documents(i).Name = sDocName) Then Exit For
        Next i
        If (i > wordApp.Documents.Count) Then Exit Loop
    Loop While (True)
```

Note: you probably don't want to close the application because maybe the user had other documents open. Maybe you should test that.

Comment: The error I get with this method (and pretty much all others) is Run-time error '462': The remote server machine does not exist or is unavailable.  Debug stops at line For i = 1 To wordApp.Documents.Count.  I suspect because word has been closed the object is no longer valid.  Neither is the object Nothing.  I need to test the object I think.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution...

```
Do While .Visible
       ' wait until the window is no longer visible       
Loop
```

Does exactly what I was looking for, waits until word is closed and then continues with the MS Access VBA script.

Comment: Do While _what_ is visible? wordApp or wordDoc?

Comment: This loop replaces the do until loop at in the original post.  So it is wordApp.

Comment: What happens if you open another document in the instance of Word that Access creates, and then close the document that Access opened?

Answer (score 0):

Building on what Paul has entered this uses a different method to test if the document is open.

```
Sub Test()

    Dim wordApp As Word.Application
    Dim wordDoc As Word.Document
    Dim sDocName As String

    sDocName = "<Full path to document>"

    Set wordApp = New Word.Application

    With wordApp
        Set wordDoc = .Documents.Open(sDocName, , False)
        .Visible = True
        .Activate

        Do
            DoEvents
        Loop While FileIsOpen(sDocName)

    End With

    MsgBox "Finished"

End Sub

Public Function FileIsOpen(FullFilePath As String) As Boolean

    Dim ff As Long

    On Error Resume Next

    ff = FreeFile()
    Open FullFilePath For Input Lock Read As #ff
    Close ff
    FileIsOpen = (Err.Number <> 0)

    On Error GoTo 0

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue with checking to see if `wordApp Is Nothing` is that VBA doesn't know to dereference the object when it is closed externally. In other words, when the document to which wordApp refers is closed, the pointer to the object becomes **bogus** but not `Nothing`. To trap for the event, you can do a meaningless call to the document object in the loop, and exit if an error occurs:

```
On Error Resume Next
With wordDoc
  Do
    DoEvents
    'This will only occur if there is an error:
    If .Visible<>.Visible Then Exit Do
  Loop
End With
Err.Clear
On Error Goto 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I just tested with no loop or anything else. The macro code in Access waited until the instance of the Word application was closed before it finished executing. Here's what I tested, and the MsgBox only executed after I quit Word:

```
' Open the document
With wordApp
    Set wordDoc = .Documents.Add

    ' Pass data
    With wordDoc
        .Variables("bmArchitectCompanyName").Value = "Hello"
        .Variables("bmArchitectCompanyAddress").Value = "Hello"
        .Variables("bmArchitectCompanyPostCode").Value = "Hello"
        .Variables("bmArchitectContactFirstName").Value = "Hello"
        .Content.Text = "test"
        '.Variables("bmProjectTitle").Value = ProjectTitle
        '.Fields.Update
    End With
    .Visible = True
    .Activate

    ' Display a success message
    MsgBox "Success!"
    Set wordDoc = Nothing
    Set wordApp = Nothing
End With
```

> Note that you want to be sure to set the objects to `Nothing` or
>   you're likely to get error messages the next time you run the code
>   because it will leave the instance of WinWord open in memory.

Comment: That doesn't work for me.  The script runs and the message box appears WHILE word is open.  I need MS Access to wait until Word is closed..